# Different memory for one variable from .bss section

Tags: gcc, linker, ld, linker-scripts

I have a huge DDR memory (2GB) with huge access time and tiny internal RAM (1MB) with tiny access time. At this moment I have whole .bss section in DDR. The .bss section contains one often used variable from external library. How can I move it from slow DDR to fast RAM? There is no way to fit whole .bss in RAM and also I can't modify external library.

```
Disassembly of section .bss:
8000008c <some_variable>
```

```
.bss (NOLOAD) : {
   . = ALIGN(4);
   __bss_start = .;
   *(.bss)
   *(.bss.*)
   *(.gnu.linkonce.b.*)
   *(COMMON)
   . = ALIGN(4);
   __bss_end = .;
} > DDR
```

I tried someting like that, but its not work.

```
.bssFAST (NOLOAD) : {
   . = ALIGN(4);
   file.o:some_variable(.bss)
   . = ALIGN(4);
} > RAM
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried someting like that, but its not work.

That couldn't work: the linker doesn't work at the variable level, it works on *sections*.

If `foo.o`s `.bss` section is not too large, you may be able to move that entire section into `.bssFAST`.

If you can't do that, your only other choice is to binary-patch `foo.o` such that:

1. It has a new `.bssFAST` section (`objcopy --add-section` should work) and
2. Change `some_variable` so it's in that new section (this should be relatively easy -- updating `.st_shndx` should do it).